# Unable to adjust volume in Kubuntu 16

Tags: volume-control

When following the standard instructions for adjusting volume (click the sound menu on the menu bar and move the volume slider left or right) I get no change in volume until "Mute".  All I get is full volume, regardless of slider position (percentage), or Mute.  Other than that, sound is working just fine.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: DGX [Xonar DGX], device 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: DGX [Xonar DGX], device 1: Digital [Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I doubt it is a hardware issue, as this was working fine on my previous install of 16.04LTS until I broke it, and did a fresh install on a brand new drive

*edit - adding requested output

```
    $ pactl list sinks
Sink #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_06_04.0.analog-stereo
    Description: CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio] Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 56797 /  87% / -3.73 dB,   front-right: 56797 /  87% / -3.73 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_06_04.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "Multichannel"
        alsa.id = "Multichannel"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "Xonar DGX"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media Oxygen HD Audio at 0xec00, irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_oxygen"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:06:04.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:04.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "13f6"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics Inc"
        device.product.id = "8788"
        device.product.name = "CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "352800"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio] Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "CMI8786"
        alsa.components = "CS4245 CMI8786"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000)
    Active Port: analog-output-headphones
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please [edit] your question to include more info. What graphic, where? At the very least include a link to an image so that we have some idea what you are talking about.

Comment: That's a start but we'll need more: the output of `pactl list sinks` would help. Also, can you try whether you can gradually adjust the volume with on a lower level, i. e. ALSA instead of PulseAudio? You can control ALSA devices with `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer (GUI).

Comment: alsa has no effect - same issue - I can "adjust" the volume, but it does not affect the actual output

Command output is being added to my original question